# How to align within tabular?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cv

I was preparing my CV for graduate school application using Overleaf and had a question.

Right now, I have a section that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to have the "(Date: )" parts aligned, and the scores aligned as well.

The code that I currently have is something like:

```
 \Large{Test Scores}
 & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l l}
 GRE (Date: August 18th, 2018): 
 & Verbal: 163/170 \\ 
 & Quantitative: 169/170 \\ 
 & Analytical writing: 5.5/6 \\
 TOEFL iBT (Date: March 16th, 2019): 
 & Reading: 30/30 \\ 
 & Listening: 27/30 \\ 
 & Speaking: 30/30 \\ 
 & Writing: 28/30 \\ 
 & Total: 115/120 
 \end{tabular}
```

I tried using a `\begin{align}` but the use of ampersands has left me a bit confused.

Any tips or advice are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `align` is explicitly math, and inappropriate here.  I've added the more generic tag "horizontal alignment, which is what you're really looking for, but left (the incorrect) `align` because that's mentioned in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  {\Large Test Scores} &
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l l l r @{/} l}
   GRE & (Date: August 18th, 2018):
      & Verbal:             & 163&170 \\
     && Quantitative:       & 169&170 \\
     && Analytical writing: & 5.5&6   \\
   TOEFL iBT & (Date: March 16th, 2019): 
      & Reading:            &  30&30  \\
     && Listening:          &  27&30  \\
     && Speaking:           &  30&30  \\
     && Writing:            &  28&30  \\
     && Total:              & 115&120
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```